# Rails not serving static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I'm running the latest version of Thin, Rails, and Ruby. The relevant parts of my build script are:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
export RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
# generate static assets
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
# restart server
rails server thin -d
```

And in my production.rb I have

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

And I include these files in my view using

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

This successfully compiles my assets and moves them to the /public/assets folder. However, none of these assets are actually served when loading the page. The generated HTML is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css" />
<script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

These don't have the digests included in the filename, so I believe they're incorrect. Attempting to manually load the filenames both with and without their digest included all fail with a 404 as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't those link tags point to `app/assets` directory instead of `public`?

Comment: I'm not sure, the documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the js files under `app/assets/javascript`.

put the css files under `app/assets/stylesheets`.

All your js and css files are loaded in the header of `application.html.erb`, which loads the `application.css` and `application.js`. This is what these two lines of code does.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

These two files, there is a line `require_tree .` which loads all the files in the corresponding directory:

```
app/assets/javascript
app/assets/stylesheets
```

I usually use `public` folder only for external libraries when I am not using a CDN. And you will need to explicitly include them in the `application.js` and `application.css` file.